# Photo Competition 2021-07-26: Music

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Music

Either *literal* (instruments, musicians, performance) or figurative (geometric or natural patterns which evoke the patterns of music).

This theme was suggested by [mattdm](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/125609/photo-competition-2021-07-26-music?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on August 9, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Musical urinal

[image]

Found this interesting urinal on a trip through England.

Camera: Xiaomi Mi 9T Pro
Lens: f/1.8 1/20 4.77mm ISO2422
Location: The Bell Pub in Ticehurst, England

Comment: They should have installed an alto version for children!

Answer (score 17):

### Halftime Hip Hop

[image: Halftime Hip Hop]

One of the Drum Majors for the Jackson-Olin High School Marching Mustangs Band performs at halftime of a first-round playoff game in Birmingham, Alabama November 9, 2018.

Canon EOS 7D Mark II + EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II @ 200mm. ISO 3200, f/2.8, 1/500.

<sub>Cropped from 3,648x5,472 (2:3) to 3,483x4,644 (3:4) before resizing to 1,800x2,400 to meet the Photography SE size limit</sub>

Answer (score 9):

## The Jazz vibe

[image: Jazz Energy]

An underground Jazz club in London. 
I wanted to catch the energy of the band so the motion blur IS intentional!. 
Here are the violinist and the bass player.

F4.3

1/8th second

19mm

ISO 1600

Answer (score 7):

No idea whose fist that is, but I snapped it at Machine Head, at Download Festival in (I think) 2012

On OnePlus 1

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Dancin' in the Backlight

[image: Dancin' in the Backlight]

Nikon D200, Nikkor 50mm f1.8, ISO100, 1/250s, f18

A couple at dance practice. Backlit by two 1600ws studio strobes. Shot this the day I got remote triggers for my studios lights to play with not being tethered to the strobes.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Zee on the Steinway]
Geared up and ready to play.  Zee posing atop a Steinway model A+.  Shot using an old Sony DSC-R1

Answer (score 4):

In the calm before the storm - my band supported Monster Magnet in Glasgow in September 2018. I took this as we prepared for sound check. The adrenaline had not yet kicked in, and I just liked the peaceful nature of the photo.

Shot on Oneplus 5 [image]

Answer (score 4):

### Still Rockin'

[image: Still Rockin']

Veteran Muscle Shoals keyboardist/composer Noble Thurman, and Rock & Roll Hall of Fame member Dewey "Spooner" Oldham lean into a shared microphone to sing backup vocals for the penultimate song at 'Honey in the Hive', a 2021 W.C. Handy Music Festival event featuring Christine Ohlman (The Saturday Night Live "Beehive Queen") & The Decoys with many special guests. Thurman, a member of The Decoys, played the entire concert. Oldham was an unannounced very special guest who sang a duet with Ohlman on a song he and Dan Penn wrote in 1967 for The Inspirations and was later covered by Diana Ross & The Supremes with the Temptations, Barbra Streisand, Wilson Pickett, and many others: "Sweet Inspiration".

"Spooner" re-emerged from sidestage when the band kicked into this song, "Mustang Sally", and played the same piano part he had backed Wilson Pickett with at Pickett's recording session 55 years ago in 1966.

Canon EOS 5D Mark III + EF 24-70mm f/2.8 L @ 59mm. ISO 3200, f/2.8, 1/800.

Location: Shoals Marriott Conference Center, Florence, Alabama
Date: Monday, July 26, 2021

Answer (score 3):

**Street Music**
[image: Street Musicians In Kadıköy, İstanbul]

January 2019 — Kadıköy, İstanbul

Ilford HP5 Film Using Canon AE1 Program Camera, self developed, scanned from the negative with Epson V370.

Answer (score 3):

**Cellist and Fan, Central Park**

A cellist and fan under the Greywacke Arch in Central Park, October 2017.

Canon EOS 6D, f/1.2, 1/4000, ISO 3200, 85mm f/1.2L prime lens.

[image: Cellist and Fan, Central Park]

Answer (score 1):

**Flora**

A Morris dancer in action at Warwick Folk Festival in 2017

Olympus PEN-5, f/4.9, 1/500, ISO-200 with the kit 40-150 lens at 96mm.

[image: Morris dancer]

Answer (score 1):

**On the move**

Morris dancers moving between performances at Warwick Folk Festival in 2017

Olympus PEN-5, f/5, 1/500, ISO-200 with the kit 40-150 lens at 85mm.

[image: On the move]

Answer (score 1):

**Bass Punk**

The bass player from the band, Purple Pam and the Flesh Eaters performing at a free concert in Tompkins Square Park, New York, in August 2018.

Canon EOS 6D, f/4.0, 1/800, ISO 6400, 40 mm with the 28-105mm zoom.

[image: Purple Pam and the Flesh Eaters Bass Player, Tompkins Square Park]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Neumes on vellum]

At the Vatican archives, chant music in neume notation on vellum.

Sept. 14, 2013

EOS 6D, 24-105L, 1/250, f/4, ISO 10,000